# Return type with integers

Tags: java

I'm making a small program that determines the minimum integer of 3 integers. I'm having problems returning the integers back into the variable answer.

Here Is how I imagine the program working;

PROGRAM RUNS:

- Looks for Method called "Minimumum" with the listed argument.
- Determines the minimum integer and returns it back to the method Minimum
- This value gets stored in the answer variable

Code:

```
public class Method {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int answer = Minimum(20, 40, 50);
    }

    public static int Minimum(int first, int second, int third) {
        if ((first < (second) && (first < third))) {
            return first;
        } else if ((second < (first) && (second < third))) {
            return second;
        } else if (((third < first) && (third < second))) {
            return (third);
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I normally love ()'s, but you have too many even for me. 2. What is the "problem" you are having?

Comment: At the moment, your code won't compile, because there is a possibility, based on you conditions, that none of them will be meet (the compiler is complaining)

Comment: You should add return statement in the last else case. Or throw an exception. Or this will cause compile error

Comment: Your logic aside, the main problem you'll have there is … your method doesn't return anything in your “error” clause. Perhaps you want to signal the error by throwing an exception. (Yes, I know it's unreachable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a result in all cases, so your `else` block is incorrect. Do you really think there is a fourth case ? No, there isn't : there are three integers so the minimum is one of those three, meaning there only are 3 cases... Simply remove the `else` block. By the way, why do you use *so many* parentheses ? It's useless, and unreadable.

```
public static int Minimum(int first, int second, int third){
    if (first < second && first < third) 
       return first; 
    else if (second < first && second < third)
       return second;
    else
       return third;
}
```

As noted by the others, this is not sufficient to make your method correct. Indeed, you don't care about strict inequality here because when two numbers are the same, you can choose either of them as the minimum. This code breaks if the two first parameters are equal. To fix it, simply use `<=` instead of `<` (everywhere).

Comment: lol sorry, I never have gotten feeback on the code I write :(.

Comment: There is a fourth case: at least two of the numbers are the same. The comparisons don't take that into account. And your code will also give the wrong result for example the numbers 1, 1, 2000.

Comment: I did not try to fix the code further, I simply explained why this one was not compiling. The method can be written in three `if-else if` blocks, that's my answer. But the OP indeed needs to use `<=` instead

Comment: @KapookyHandy yeah, not really... use parentheses when it is mandatory because of operators precedence (like `(3 + 5) * 2`) or when it's not clear to the average programmer which operator has a higher precedence than another (like `1 & (3 + 2)`). I find it extremely rare to have such a situation where you think parentheses should be explicit even if they don't change the result.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks a bit complicated.

```
int Minimum(int first, int second, int third) {
    int min = first;
    if (second < min) {
        min = second;
    } 
    if (third < min)  {
        min = third;
    } 
    return min; 
}
```

This looks creepy, but it should do it.

Hope it helps to understand.

Comment: The readability was the aim of this answer. I would just call the min method from Math class. But I guess it was not the answer he wanted.

Comment: This also minimizes the number of comparisons (like in the answer of Paul Boddington). However, this does not really tell the OP why his original code was not compiling

Comment: Can I use ifs statement for first condition then else statement for the second condition?  And the code is really nice :)

Comment: No, because if the first expression (comparison of first and second number) would be true, then the else (check for third number) statement would not be entered. And thank you. :-)

Comment: ohhhh yeah I just noticed what would have happened if "if else" was implemented... I also can't use "if, else if" because then I would need a third condition. Thanks I understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return in your final `else` block. But you could simplify your code with `Math.min(int, int)`. Something like,

```
public static int Minimum(int first, int second, int third) {
    return Math.min(first, Math.min(second, third));
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but "maybe" the OP can't use "library" functions, but you still get a +1 from me for a simple solution

Comment: @madprogrammer, how do you usually copy and paste code into SE? I just paste it in, highlight, and CTRL+K but sometimes a chunk will be left in non-coded format.

Comment: @KapookyHandy I do lots of different things, for example, I may throw into NetBeans and do auto format before pasting into the SO, either pre-adding the <tab> or using the code format option of the SO editor.  I may also put the code into a second editor and replace the <tab>s with <spaces>, as they don't mix well together

Answer (score 0):

Minimum function should always return the integer value in any case. After else, add return statement.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8+ your method could also look as follows:

```
public static int minimum(Integer val1, Integer val2, Integer val3){
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{val1, val2, val3});
    return list.stream().min((Integer v1, Integer v2) -> v1 < v2 ? 0 : 1 ).get();
}
```